# How to properly get screen rotation programmatically?

Tags: xorg, screen, qt, xrandr

I need to programatically obtain screen rotation. I'm using Qt and the X extension XRandr. I'm trying the following:

```
Display *dpy;
Window root;
XRRScreenConfiguration *conf;
Rotation rotation;

int screen;

dpy = QX11Info::display();
root =  QX11Info::appRootWindow();
conf = XRRGetScreenInfo(dpy, root);
screen = DefaultScreen(dpy);
XRRRotations(dpy, screen, &rotation);

qDebug() << "CURRENT ROTATION:" << rotation;
```

The problem is that independently of the current screen orientation, set through Displays settings app from Ubuntu, the CURRENT ROTATION output is always 1.

Does anyone knows why?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I finally found the answer to this. I'm using Qt. Some of the calls are from Qt to get the Window and Screen of X11.

```
Display *dpy;
Window root = this->winId();
dpy = QX11Info::display();

XRRScreenResources *scrres = XRRGetScreenResources(dpy, root);
XRRCrtcInfo *crtcInfo = XRRGetCrtcInfo(dpy, scrres, *scrres->crtcs);

crtcInfo->rotation can be 1, 2, 4, or 8
```

Hope this helps someone in the future.